# how to fit image width to picturebox not height in c# windows form

Tags: c#, picturebox, windows-forms-designer, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to display an image in a PictureBox which is in a panel:

Actual panel width is 600 and height is 300. I set AutoScroll to true and Anchor Property is set to the top left right. After placing a picturebox within that panel I set sizemode as AutoSize.

If I try to browse an image which has a width of 882px, it is trying to display both horizontal and vertical scroll bars, but I want to display image width to fit the panel width and then show the vertical scroll bar.

If I try to browse an image having a width of 400px, it displays only the  vertical scroll bar but the image width is half of the panel.

I want to display the image width always as the same size as the panel width and containing a vertical scroll bar.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to scale the image to fit the panel width. Calculate the ratio `width/height` of image and use this to scale the image to desired width.

Comment: If you want to fit the image to the picturebox use `PictureBox.SizeMode = StretchImage`.  Else if you just want to change the width use: `(Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, new Size(x,y)));` where x is the width and y is the height